# MarkdownTextBlock v1.4.1 image support in UWP app

Tags: uwp, windows-community-toolkit

Is the image support in the MarkdownTextBlock 1.4.1 only at the end of line?

I have a line such as :
If you can see [settingsImage] click **Continue**.

my markdown is as follows:

```
If you can see ![settings](ms-appx://App1/Assets/Settings.png) click **Continue**.
```

The image shows up correctly but the line ends there. 
**Output Displayed**:

```
If you can see [settingsImage]
```

Is this expected behavior? Is there a way to embed an image in the middle of a sentence? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for as I know, you can't have an image in the middle of a sentence.

Post your issue in [UWP Community Toolkit issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/issues)

Comment: here is the link to bug for anyone interested - https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/issues/1188